# HTML 2d canvas as texture on webgl canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to add a canvas with context `2d` as a `texture` to a `webgl` canvas based on this example [here](https://delphic.me.uk/tutorials/webgl-text). The texture appears to be blank on the `webgl` canvas but the image is loaded when I append the texture canvas to the`DOM` on it's own. What may I be missing here?

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const textureCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    textureCanvas.width = 200
    textureCanvas.height = 200
    const ctx = textureCanvas.getContext('2d')
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/uIEexIc.jpg";
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'

    img.onload = (i) => {
      
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200, 200)
    }

   
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    const canvasTexture = gl.createTexture();
    
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, canvasTexture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureCanvas); 
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

Comment: (unrelated) You don't need to set `image.crossOrigin` to anonymous, that's the default value

Answer (score 1):

A canvas can not be used as a "live" texture.

In other words, when your code calls `gl.texImage2D(....., textureCanvas)` what happens is the contents of the canvas *at that moment in time* is copied to the texture just once.

In your code above the flow is this

1. create a canvas
2. create an image
3. set the src and setup an onload function
4. create a webgl texture
5. copy the blank canvas to the texture via texImage2D
6. sometime later the image finishes loading and the onload function is called
7. the image is drawn into the canvas.

You need to wait for the image to be drawn into the canvas before you call `gl.texImage2D`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to investigate the problem.

It seems, that forcing the texture canvas to have dimensions as power of 2 fixes the texture visibility.

You can try to replace this block in your code:

```js
img.onload = (i) => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200, 200)
}
```

to this block:

```js
img.onload = (ev) => {
  const w = getPowerOfTwo(img.width);
  const h = getPowerOfTwo(img.height);
  textureCanvas.width = w
  textureCanvas.height = h
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
  handleLoadedTexture(textureCanvas);
}
```

Here I force textureCanvas to have width and height to be power or 2. The function is here:

```js
function getPowerOfTwo(value, pow) {
  var pow = pow || 1;
  while (pow < value) {
    pow *= 2;
  }
  return pow;
}
```

Also notice the code `handleLoadedTexture(textureCanvas);`. Here I redraw (update) the texture with new loaded image.

All other code you can test here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x79tfnyw/3/). To be sure, that texture is served from canvas, I've added `'Hello World'` text above the image (see `handleLoadedTexture`).